# ruby script/rails server fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the ruby world.
I want to run an existing Rails project, but I get the following error:

```
$ruby script/rails server
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.0/ext/json/ext/json/ext/parser.bundle: undefined class/module Encoding (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
```

Should I install other packages or another version of rails?
If I write a small project using  `rails new xxx` then `$ruby script/rails server` works.

BTW: I am in mac.

Thank you!

Comment: you should execute bundle install inside your existing ruby project, let me see what happen

Comment: `bundle install
    Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
    Using i18n (0.6.0) 
    Using multi_json (1.3.4) 
    .....
    Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

Comment: What version of rails are you running? Am guessing 3.x. If so then start the server with `rails s`. Also, you might want to include the full error message.

Comment: rails server
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-06-06 09:50:38][HireFire] Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job detected!
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]

Comment: It looks like this project using the old version nokogiri (1.5.2), and the newest nokogiri is 1.5.3, and the all environment match nokogiri 1.5.3. So my question is --- Is it possible let this project use new nokogiri, how ?

Comment: I done it finally. I remove nokogiri and reinstall it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The correct commands in different versions of rails are:

rails 2.3

```
ruby script/server
```

rails 3

```
rails server #  or ruby script/rails server
```

It is possible that the existing project is rails 2.3 and your environment is rails 3.0.

Comment: It is not 2.3.
`ls script/`

`cucumber     delayed_job  rails`